# Getting connection refused or connection timeout** error in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am getting **connection refused or connection timeout** error in jmeter when i click on Start Remote All link under run menu after completing setting for distribution testing.

Please provide some answers

Hope for the Good response

Thanks!

Vinod

Comment: Please add some code, so we can see where the problem is!

Comment: So your script runs fine in normal mode but gives error in distributed environment ? If thats the case then it seems that you have not configured your distributed env correctly. Please provide more details about your configurations so we can assist. Details like which OS platform, network. how many machines etc.